# How to add multiple overlays at different positions in an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.reddot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #D03C3C;
  border-radius: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left:195px;
}
.reddot_2 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #D03C3C;
  border-radius: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left:135px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/z5BV8j6/l.png" alt="Map" class="img-fluid" width="200px" height="200px">
  <div class="reddot"></div>
  <div class="reddot_2"></div>
</div>
```

How to add and delete multiple overlays (Red Rectangles) using simple buttons to an image and the adding of overlays would have a simple text box of top and left pixel input as shown in the CSS so that the red rectangles can be added to the position I inputted into the textbox? Any help will be appreciated :)

Thank you for reading and have a nice day!

For now, I am writing multiple red-dot classes to be overlay with the image but it is tedious.
`<div class="reddot"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Javascript to add and remove the rectangles dynamically when the buttons are pressed. Here are an example demonstrating how to add some rectangles based on a fixed list of positions. At least with the following code, you will not have to write multiple red-dot classes.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    const reddotContainer = document.getElementById('reddot-container');

    [{top: '-5px', left: '195px'},
        {top: '95px', left: '135px'},
        {top: '50px', left: '50px'},
        {top: '10px', left: '135px'}].forEach(reddotPosition => {
      const newReddot = document.createElement('div');
      newReddot.className = 'reddot';
      newReddot.style.left = reddotPosition.left;
      newReddot.style.top = reddotPosition.top;
       reddotContainer.append(newReddot);
    });
});
```

```css
.reddot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #D03C3C;
  border-radius: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" id="reddot-container">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/z5BV8j6/l.png" alt="Map" class="img-fluid" width="200px" height="200px">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your effort in your answer!! I have not touched Javascript for 3 years already :)